# Pass by reference works in C but does not work with C++ for this code

Tags: c++, c

In my below code , It compiles and runs when I use it as a c file , but gives an error when I run it as cpp file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ploc_t {
                 int num;
                 ploc_t *right;
                };


ploc_t *create_ploc(int *point , int *triangles, int n , int m){


    // just for testing
    ploc_t *result;
    result=(ploc_t*)malloc(sizeof(ploc_t));
    return result;
}



int main( )
{

    int points[1][2];
    int triangles[1][2];

    points[0][1]=2;
    points[0][2]=4;

    triangles[0][1]=8;
    triangles[0][2]=6;


    create_ploc(points,triangles,3,4);


}
```

Error which I get in when using cpp file is :

Invalid arguments candidates are: plot_t(int*,int*,int,int)

Why is this error? and how can it be resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works in C but `int[]` (i.e., a 1 dimensional array) is not the same type as `int[][]` (i.e., a 2 dimensional array).

Comment: Are you sure it can work in C?

Comment: Note that `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` are both pure C++.  Using the name `ploc_t` without either the `struct` prefix or `typedef struct ploc_t ploc_t;` before the structure definition is also C++ and not C.

Comment: How can you pass by reference in C when the C language doesn't support references?  Both languages support pointers, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between C and C++ in this instance is that in C, what you're doing (passing a pointer to `int[2]` to a function expecting a pointer to `int`) is legal although discouraged, whereas in C++ you're not allowed to do it. So in C, the compiler will issue a warning. If you're not using the `-Wall` flag, you might not see the warning. In C++, it doesn't matter whether you used `-Wall` or not (although you *always* should) because it's an error and the compile will fail.

Arrays passed as parameters "decay" to a pointer to the array element type. (That's not the only case in which arrays decay to pointers, but it's the one relevant to this question.) Your arrays are of type `int[][2]`, so the element type is `int[2]`. Consequently, when you use them as arguments, they decay to `int(*)[2]`, which is C/C++'s idiosyncratic way of saying "a pointer to a two-element array of ints".

What's the difference between a pointer to an `int` and a pointer to an `int[2]`? One important difference is the size of the target:

```
int a[2];
int* p = a;
p++;
// p now points to a[2]; it was incremented by sizeof(int)

int aa[10][2];
int(*pp)[2] = aa;
pp++;
// pp now points to aa[2]; it was incremented by sizeof(int[2])
```

Rather than fighting with the syntax for pointer to arrays, you probably want to define you function to accept two-dimensional arrays:

```
ploc_t *create_ploc(int points[][2], int triangles[][2], int n , int m);
```

But you could, with exactly the same semantics, write out the decayed types:

```
ploc_t *create_ploc(int (*points)[2], int (*triangles)[2], int n , int m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your main:

```
int points[1][2];
int triangles[1][2];
```

"points" and "triangles" are two-dimensional arrays. The first two arguments to create_ploc() are pointers to integers. Passing these two-dimensional arrays directly into the function is *not* passing a pointer. I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but a couple of ways to solve this are:

1)

```
int points[1];
int triangles[1]; // both one-dimensional arrays of ints (int*)
```

2)

```
create_ploc(points[0],triangles[0],3,4); // passing in a one-dimensional array of ints (int*)
```

Comment: They're not int**. They're `int(*)[2]`, i.e. pointers to `int[2]`. The `int[2]` is a real type, it does not decay.